# Samsung Keyboard Suppress

Tags: android, keyboard, galaxy

With  a bluetooth keyboard connected, the Note 2 forces the switch back to the Samsung keyboard.  This is a problem, as the Samsung keyboard always pops up when I'm trying to type with my external, taking up screen space and defeating half the purpose.  I could write an app that forces the switch back, probably, but I'd still have to hit Enter/OK everytime the keyboard connects.  I disabled the Samsung keyboard altogether, but the OK button still shows up.  Is there some sort of service that does this or something?  Because if I can't block/disable whatever it is, it's going to mess with my workflow, seeing as I bought this K810 to switch between multiple devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a code snippet I use in order to prevent the keyboard to popup at application start:

```
public void hideSoftKeyboard(View v) {
            Activity activity = (Activity) v.getContext();
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)    activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

I think that if you can detenct the event with:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#keyboard
There are some flags, which indicate what's the inserted keyboard.

Or just try this one, even though i didn't test it:

```
public boolean onEvaluateInputViewShown() {
     return false;
}
```

Let me know then of the results.
Thanks